# Applying the same styling to the div container not doing the same as applying it separately to elements within?

Tags: html, css

I put 3 input labels into a div id called everything. I wanted to apply the same padding to each of the 3 label elements within so I tried adding the styling into the #everything class.

```
#everything {
  color:blue;
  display:inline-block;
  padding: 5px 10px 5px 0px;  }
```

The end result was [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wnxIC.png) but I wanted [spacing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vnub4.png). The padding didn't work.

When I applied those separately to each of the label ID's it spaced it out how I wanted to. How come I'm able to set everything in the div to the color blue but padding doesn't affect everything the same way when I write it in the div? What am I doing wrong?

```
<div id="everything">
    <form action="url to submit data to" id="survey-form"> 
      <label for="name" id="name-label"> Name </label>
        <input type="text" required id="name" placeholder="Enter your name"></input><br>
      <label for="email" id="email-label"> Email </label>
        <input type="email" required id="email" placeholder="Enter your email">  </iput><br>
      <label for="number" id="number-label"> Age </label>
        <input type="number" id="number" min="10" max="85" placeholder="Age"></input>  
</div>

#name-label, #email-label, #number-label{
  display:inline-block;
  padding: 5px 10px 5px 0px;
  
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When u apply the padding in the div#everything, the padding will only be applied into the div container itself, not the elements inside the div#everything tag. kindly refer to the following example:

1. With padding defined in the div#everything:

[image]

2. Without padding in the div#everything:

[image]

**Padding value is based on the value u defined (padding: 5px 10px 5px 0px;).
**I made the div#everything background to red, for u to see the padding clearly.

Comment: Thank you so much! It makes it a lot easier to see the difference from your pictures.

Answer (score 1):

The label colors aren't set so they're inherited from the parent. Which in this case is blue since it's set in `#everything`

`padding` isn't inherited from the parent so you would need to declare it for the `<label>` tags

You could do

```
#everything {
  color: blue;
}

#everything label {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 5px 10px 5px 0px; 
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Are there certain elements like padding that are just not inherited from the parent? I was under the impression that the child inherits everything from the parent unless it is overwritten later on in the child's class. Sorry still very new to this!

Comment: You could probably scour w3org and look at the properties to find out if they're 'supposed' to be inherited. But I dont think there is a curated list that says which are and aren't. 


Color property docs
https://www.w3.org/TR/css-color-3/


Not all properties will be inherited, padding would definetly cause some unwanted results of the children all inherited the parents padding.